# Purpose of functions in arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm new to programming. I recently started with Javascript and in one of the topics there was create an array of functions. My question is what are those useful for? I didn't get the idea behind. Can someone help me understand?

Update: to make the question more clear I will use an example a colleague shared. Let's say we have this:

```
var twoDimensionalImageData = ...
    var operations = [
        function(pixel) { blur(pixel); },
        function(pixel) { invert(pixel); },
        function(pixel) { reflect(pixel); }
    ];

foreach(var pixel in twoDimensionalImageData)
     foreach(var func in operations)
        func( pixel );
```

Can this be achieved without the use of functions in array? Or can this be achieved without the use of function(pixel) in operations array? If yes I would like to understand why the function in array can be better than normal functions. What's the benefit of it?

Comment: Could you provide example to demonstrate what you are asking about?

Comment: What if you had a situation where you needed to decide what sort of action to take, and the decision was based on a number between 0 and 10?

Comment: Basically a array of functions is nothing I needed in my time as a "beginner". It's something for advanced design patterns

Answer (score 2):

I can see a possible use for an array-of-functions if you're wanting to massage data; rather than using function currying and composition, just apply a series of functions to the data, like macro steps. This might be useful in imaging applications, think of Photoshop's "Actions" feature.

```
var twoDimensionalImageData = ...
var operations = [
    function(pixel) { blur(pixel); },
    function(pixel) { invert(pixel); },
    function(pixel) { reflect(pixel); }
];

foreach(var pixel in twoDimensionalImageData)
    foreach(var func in operations)
        func( pixel );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list of functions as a list of callbacks or have functions as listeners (instead of objects) of an Observer pattern.

Observer:
This is a very famous software design pattern. It consists of having one main object or, say, Entity, that lots of other objects are interested into. When this main Entity changes its attribute or something happens to it, it tells whoever is interested (or listening) that something happened (and what did).

List of callbacks:
Could be useful when, say, you made an Ajax request (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) to update your news feed and then you want to also execute many other steps. All you have to do if you have this list of functions is iterate through it and call them. (Yes, you could call them in a single function, but keeping them in an array would give it a lot of flexibility).

In both cases, it's very easy to "know" what functions you have to call :)

Comment: The asker is new to programming, and your answer uses design patterns as an example!!

Comment: I use this often - in fact (using Lists), this is how event handlers were done in a lot of C# stuff.

Comment: holy crap, let me elaborate :)